# how to insert null date value in database using asp.net 3 tier architecture

Tags: asp.net, datetime

```
if (objChildFees.childid != null)
{
        objChildFees.classstudentid = 0;
        objChildFees.classid = Convert.ToInt16(ddlClass.SelectedValue);
        objChildFees.centerid = Convert.ToInt32(Session[CommonVariables.gCentreId].ToString());
        objChildFees.roomno = 1;
        objChildFees.startdate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStartDate.Text.ToString());
        objChildFees.enddate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtEndDate.Text.ToString());
        objChildFees.newfees = Convert.ToDecimal(txtfeesamt.Text.ToString());
        objChildFees.feestype = chkFeesPay.Checked == true ? 1 : 2;
        objChildFees.childdaystype = chkfulltime.Checked == true ? 1 : 2;
        objChildFees.feepermonthforsubsidized = 0;
        objChildFees.feepermonthforpartime = 0;
        objChildFees.feepermonthforparttimesubsidized = 0;
        objChildFees.activestatus = true;
        objChildFees.withdrawaldate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtwtdate.Text);
}
```

How to add null withdrawal date in this code I am facing the error: `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`

Comment: Specify the `IFormatProvider`. Or use the `DateTime.ParseExact` method with the exact format specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `objChildFees.withdrawaldate` can be null, you can set it as a [nullable DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types). Check the value of `txtwtdate.Text` before attempting to convert it to a `DateTime?`

```
public class ChildFees 
{
  // The ? after DateTime indicates this variable should be a nullable datatype
  DateTime? withdrawldate {get; set;}
  ...
}

objChildFees.withdrawaldate = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtwtdate.Text) ? null : (DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime(txtwtdate.Text);
```

In a production system, you would likely want to use [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) to make sure the value of `txtwtdate.Text` contains a valid date string when converting to avoid exceptions thrown during conversion.

Comment: I have attempted this but showing error : Type of conditional expression can not be determine because there is no implicit conversion between <null> and <datetime>

Comment: @HarshPatel That's because the output of `Convert.ToDateTime()` is a `DateTime`, not a `DateTime?`. You need to cast the result to `DateTime?` like this: `(DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime(txtwtdate.Text)`.

Comment: Tried this code too but no result error is:SqlException (0x80131904): Procedure or function 'Sp_InsertUpdateChildEnrollmentFeesDetails' expects parameter '@withdrawaldate', which was not supplied.]

Comment: @HarshPatel You're getting that error because you didn't provide `@withdrawldate` as a parameter to your stored procedure. You can either give `@withdrawldate` a default value of null in your stored procedure or make sure you always pass `@withdrawldate` as a parameter with a value of either null or an actual date. You'll want to make sure your database field is also set to allow null values.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class Extenstions
{
    public string ToNullableString(this string value)
    {
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
         {
             return null;
         }
         
         return value;
     }
}
```

> Make sure that `withdrawaldate` property is has a nullable type (`DateTime?`)

Then used like this `Convert.ToDateTime(txtwtdate.Text.ToNullableString())`